# Cannot borrow pointer even if previous borrow is "forgotten"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I do not understand why the function **fn1** doesn't compile, i.e.
why "let z = &mut x;" cannot be assigned while previously
taken reference stored in "y" is not used anymore ("y" is reassigned
to something else).

Moreover, why both **fn2** and **fn3** do compile ok while they are doing "logically" the same thing?

**fn2** differs from **fn1** in fact, that "y" goes out of scope instead of reassigning, but that is
different only in respect to "y" pointer storage, not in respect to what is "y" pointing to.

**fn3** differs from **fn1** in fact, that "z" is assigned from "y" instead of directly from "&mut x".

```
fn fn1() {
    let mut x = 1i32;
    let mut somethingelse = 7i32;
    let mut y = &mut x;
    *y = *y + 1;
    println!("y = {}", *y);
    y = &mut somethingelse;
    println!("just something: {}", *y);
    // y is not used anymore...
    let z = &mut x;
    *z = *z + 1;
    println!("z = {}", *z);
}

fn fn2() {
    let mut x = 1i32;
    {
        let y = &mut x;
        *y = *y + 1;
        println!("y = {}", *y);
    }
    let z = &mut x;
    *z = *z + 1;
    println!("z = {}", *z);
}

fn fn3() {
    let mut x = 1i32;
    let z;
    let y = &mut x;
    *y = *y + 1;
    println!("y = {}", *y);
    z = y;
    *z = *z + 1;
    println!("z = {}", *z);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, borrow scopes are lexical, that is, they correspond to the braces in the code. There's [a bug to change this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393) to account for cases like your `fn1`, but like you see in `fn2`, there are workarounds for now.

For `fn3`, if you try to use `y` again, you will get this error:

```
error: use of moved value: `*y`
```

This is because the compiler can tell (via the statement `z = y`) that `y` is no longer needed and thus moves the mutable borrow to `z`, making `y` invalid.